# excel formula subtract valid for date from date created to give days remaining

Tags: excel, formula

I have a spreadsheet laid out like so:

```
A                         B                 C
Date Record Created       Valid For         Days Remaining
05.10.2016 - 10:00:00     1 week            6 days
03.10.2016 - 14:00:00     2 weeks           13 Days
```

I want to use a formula that will be able to subtract 1 week, 2 weeks, 3 weeks and 4 weeks from my dates in column A to give me the number of days remaining.

Is this possible and if so please can someone show me how to do this? I must have my values in column B listed as 1 week, 2 week etc. i cannot have 7 or 14 as values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the date/times in column A **real** date/times formatted as `dd.mm.yyyy - hh:mm:ss` or text that looks like a date/time? Are the values right or left aligned in the cells?

Comment: The dates in column A are real date/times format. And the text is left aligned. thanks

Comment: Real date/times are right-aligned in a cell by default. What happens when you try `=A2+1` ? Do you get `#VALUE!` or `06.10.2016 - 10:00:00
` ?

Comment: Is it only weeks in column B? Or can it be `1 week and 2 days`?

Comment: @Andreas it is only week and weeks. I.e. 1 week will be singular and then 2,3,4 will be weeks plural. No days

Answer (score 2):

Provide a custom number format for B using,

```
[Color13][>1]0 W\e\ek\s;[Color13][=1]0 W\e\ek;[Color3]0 W\e\ek\s
```

Type the weeks in as *1, 2, 3,* etc.

Provide a similar custom number format in column C using,

```
[Color13][>1]0 \D\a\y\s;[Color13][=1]0 \D\a\y;[Color3]To\d\a\y
```

With the values in column A as **real** date/times  (default right-aligned in a cell) using a number format of `dd.mm.yyyy - hh:mm:ss`, use the following formula in column C,

```
=(A2+B2*7)-TODAY()
```

With the values in column A as text-that-looks-like-a-datetime (default left-aligned in a cell), use the following formula in column C,

```
=(DATE(MID(A2, 7, 4), MID(A2, 4, 2), LEFT(A2, 2))+TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A2, 8))+B2*7)-TODAY()
```

[image: wekks_days_left]

Comment: i may be doing something wrong here as this didnt work for me and i get a #value error in column c